# Ubuntu13.10 freezes upon DVD upgrade

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, live-cd

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit and burned it to a DVD. I put it in my PC and booted to it, I chose to upgrade Ubuntu 13.10. It just froze when setting up my software, it has been about an hour of it being frozen. Should I hit the reset button and format my hard drive? All of my files are backed up to Ubuntu one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't push the reset button, I had the same problem. Ubuntu 13.10 could not upgrade my apps and that is why it froze. Wait for about another half an hour depending on how many apps you have and it should give you an error message and tell you the installation was finished. After that you should be fine, my user accounts were gone and so were most of my apps, but it is easy to get them back. That was a good idea for you to backup your files

Comment: Thanks, it gave me the error message after 20 minutes and I restarted. all my files were still on the hard drive including my virtual hard drives which I didn't backup.